# Discord Py Errors.... (TypeError: on_member_join() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'ctx' and 'channel')

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm working on my first discord bot, and I'm running into lots of problems without even getting into the complicated commands... I've worked with python before but not discord.py, and I'm finding it quite difficult. I'm running into this constant error code and it's really bugging me. Here is my code:

```
async def on_member_join(member, ctx, channel):
    channel = client.get_channel(753699172237967440)
    await channel.send(f'HQ has sent another employee to help us with our tasks, everyone say hi to {member}')
```

and the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jjclo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_member_join() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'ctx' and 'channel'
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See the docs for [on_member_join](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join), it only has one parameter: `member`.  You are getting this error because you have two extra parameters, `ctx` and `channel`.  Simply remove these to fix your issue.